# "Заменить на кофе или какао с молоком и сахаром" - к чему относится молоко?

Tags: семантика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как понимать! *Шоколад заменить на: кофе натуральный или какао со сгущенным молоком и сахаром.* Первое и второе надо понимать с молоком или это разные наименования?

Answer (score 3):

Этот вопрос не относится непосредственно к лингвистике, оба понимания возможны. Поэтому при написании лучше как-то уточнять или переформулировать фразу. А если это уже написано, уточнить у того, кто писал.

Впрочем, на бытовом уровне здесь скорее работает принцип последнего члена. Дополнение (уточнение, расшифровка) обычно относится к последнему элементу списка, если нет указаний на иное. То есть здесь скорее какао - с молоком и сахаром, а кофе - без них. Чтобы в этом убедиться, нужен контекст. Без него трудно понять, реально ли предположение, что шоколад можно в каком-то смысле заменить на кофе без молока и сахара.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза построена явно неудачно, появляется двусмысленность. Необходимо её перестроить, чтобы определения "с молоком и сахаром" или "без молока", "чёрный" и т.д. во избежание недоразумений оказалось рядом со своим определяемым словом "кофе" и "какао". :

1). *Шоколад заменить на кофе натуральный с молоком и сахаром  или на какао с  молоком и сахаром.*

2). *Шоколад заменить на кофе натуральный чёрный с сахаром   или на какао со сгущённым молоком и сахаром.*

Возможны варианты.